# Mod rewriting? slash to subdomain possible?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

can that be possible in mod rewrite? for example (mydomainname.com/myadmin) to (myadmin.mydomain.com)? how to write that in mod rewrite? so whenever the access the mydomainname.com/myadmin they get an error message of not existing.

Thanks!

--Edited---------

Sorry for that. In my website I have an admin (/myadmin) section where only moderators and administrator can access. Now there are a lot of user keep accessing it and I want to change the URL of it. Now instead of 'www.mydomain.com/MyAdmin' it would be 'MyAdmin.mydomain.com'. So whenever they go to 'www.mydomain.com/MyAdmin' they wouldn't find anything.

I just know that htaccess can do url rewriting, But I don't know how to write one.

Thank You!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Read the examples in the Apache documentation. Set the mod_rewrite log level to high to make sure the right thing is happening - if your web service doesn't let you do this, run a test server on your own computer.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /myadmin[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^myadmin - [NC,L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =myadmin.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^myadmin/ /absolute/filesystem/path/to/myadmin%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

That will result in a 404 response when requesting `/myadmin`. And `myadmin.example.com` will be internally rewritten to that specific *myadmin* directory if accessible through the file system.

Comment: Hi Gumbo,

I've been trying to test the code but have no luck to make it work.

here's what i've write in my .htaccess. 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /myadmin[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^myadmin - [NC,L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =myadmin.movietunie.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^myadmin/ /home/movietun/public_html/movie_tunie/myadmin/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

is there wrong with my code?

my site is http://movietunie.com and myadmin.movietunie.com

I still can access the http://movietunie.com/myadmin, why is that?

Thank You!

Comment: @Pennf0lio: REQUEST_URI already starts with a `/`. Try it without the `/` before `%{REQUEST_URI}`.